# How to make jquery plugin options true/false into more compact form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

In a jquery plugin options you often see true and false used like this:

```
var defaults = {
    one: 'false',
    two: 'true',
    three: 'true'
};
```

---

I was wondering if I could do something like this instead:

```
var defaults = {
    doStuff: 'three two' // order of these wouldn't matter
};
```

This code above would equal to:

```
one == false
two == true 
three == true
```

---

Question is, how could I achieve that?

Comment: You'll need to write extra lines of code to reduce the number of lines of code.

Comment: @SalmanA There is a point in what you say, **but** the goal for me is to reduce the code one needs to write to use the plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you want something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/jjyyp/)

```
(function($){

    var defaults = {
        flags : ""
    }

    $.myPlugin = function(options){
        options = $.extend(true, {}, defaults, options);

        $.each(options.flags.split(" "), function(i, v){
            options[v] = true;
        });

        if (options.one) {
            alert("one setted");
        }

        if (!options.three) {
            alert("three not set");
        }

    }


})(jQuery);


$.myPlugin({flags: "one two"});
```

Comment: I was wondering how it could be done without restricting the order of things. I can work with this.

Answer (score 0):

You could split the received string into an array, then go through each item and take each one present as "true".

Answer (score 0):

The first method is preferred because it more obvious what the code does. Compactness is not usually preferable over readability.

Comment: So, If I were to say in the options: `position: 'bottom right'` you would have hard time reading/understanding what the position is?

Answer (score 0):

You could use 1 and 0 instead of true and false, which would save a heck of a lot of characters.